# Do I lose out on anything buying the International 2013 Interactive Compendium from the Community Market?

Tags: dota-2, steam-community-market

Will I get the same perks from buying the International 2013 Interactive Compendium [from the Steam Community Market](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/The%20International%202013%20Interactive%20Compendium) as I would [buying it new](http://www.dota2.com/international/compendium/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you'll get everything you would if you bought it in the Dota 2 store.

They only differences would be that you won't contribute more money to the prize pool for the winning team and pushing us closer to <s>Techies</s> the ability to select the next hero Valve adds. I also suppose that the compendium will say that you've contributed $0.00 to the prize pool instead of the normal $2.50 that it says.

Comment: I decided to contribute to the pool and get it new. I think there may be a difference, as I was also given the [Wicked Bad Voodoo Set](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Wicked%20Bad%20Voodoo%20Set) for free.

Comment: @Louis: Oh, yeah. That's with your first purchase from the Dota 2 store, which the compendium would also get you if you bought it new.