# Was I supposed to get something extra for my first store purchase?

Tags: dota-2

I did a purchase from the Dota 2 Store (online) today and got a cheap set ("Custom of Karroch Set" for Beastmaster for 1.50tl (0.75$/0.5$)).

[This comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126814/do-i-lose-out-on-anything-buying-the-international-2013-interactive-compendium-f#comment172277_126816) states that I had to get something else (["Wicked Bad Voodoo Set"](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Wicked%20Bad%20Voodoo%20Set) (it costs more than my purchase lol)) as an extra, but I only got the set.

Is the extra-for-first-purchase still working? Or is it a bug that I didn't get the items?

Note: I own Dota 2 since the beta, so I have the Premium DLC from the beginning, and I think that not getting the extra stuff can be a bug.

Comment: [The Dota 2 wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Wicked_Bad_Voodoo_Set) seems to say that the giveaway promotion has ended, but I can't find any more specifics about when.

Comment: @cloudymusic feel free to post that as an answer, explicity stating that you couldn't find when.

Comment: I would've, but I feel like an unsourced edit on a wiki is a little bit below my standards for what I'm comfortable posting as an answer :P

Comment: @cloudymusic I tried. I really tried. Did I live up to your standards?

Comment: @Yann That seems a little passive-aggressive, but thanks for all of your effort regardless.

Comment: @cloudymusic It does a bit, sorry, didn't mean that at all. It was more a case of finishing a search as well as I could and a little guilt at it not amounting to much more than what you put as a comment.

Comment: @Yann No worries, I'm glad you took the time to put together as much evidence as could be managed. I wouldn't have felt comfortable posting "I dunno, this wiki edit says you can't get it anymore", but I think you've gone pretty clearly above and beyond that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to find a source for the statement on the wiki page for the [wicked bad voodoo set](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Wicked_Bad_Voodoo_Set), which states that the promotion has ended.

I started going through all of the [patch notes](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Patches), and I successfully determined that it probably happened before Febuary 24th 2015, assuming that it was documented in that wiki at all. However, there's a lot of patches. I have written a script that should look through all of them, but I'm bad at python, and it might not turn up anything. I'll edit if I find anything though.

**Edit**: I finished searching through the patch notes. There's no explicit reference to the promotion ending that I could find. However, in [the June 20, 2013](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/June_20,_2013_Patch) patch, some files (dota_item_wicked_bad_voodoo_set.png, dota_item_wicked_bad_voodoo_set_large.png) were added to the econ folder which looks like the image being added to the store. This is the most likely contender for me for when the promotion either started or finished. Probably finished, but that's based off a gut feeling and wishful thinking.

**Tl;Dr** The promotion has ended.

Comment: Thanks for answering, thanks for searching, thanks for everything.

Comment: You found it I guess, get a bounty!

Comment: Asap (23 hours) I'll give bounty to you.

Comment: Here you go, 50 rep bounty! Thanks for the research.

Comment: @ardaozkal Thanks very much, I'll pay it forwards some day soon.